# Converting from Char to Int with qFromBigEndian says: "No matching function for call to"

Tags: c++, qt, type-conversion, endianness

I am trying to read incoming data from a QTcpSocket but it gives me the error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'qFromBigEndian(char [4])'
         qint32 peekedSize = qFromBigEndian<qint32> (buffer);
```

What am I doing wrong?

This is my function:

```
void TcpServer::readIncomingData(){
    if(mDebug)
        qDebug() << "readIncomingData()";

    QTcpSocket * tcpSocket = (QTcpSocket*)sender();

    while(true){
        if (tcpSocket->bytesAvailable() < 4){
            break;
        }
        char buffer[4];
        tcpSocket->peek(buffer, 4);
        qint32 peekedSize = qFromBigEndian<qint32> (buffer);
        if (peekedSize==0xffffffffu) // null string
            peekedSize = 0;
        peekedSize += 4;

        QString str;
        QDataStream(tcpSocket) >> str;
        emit stringHasBeenRead(str);
    }
}
```

I have included the headers:

```
#include <QtNetwork>
#include <QtEndian>
#include <QtCore>
#include <QDataStream>
#include <QtGlobal>
```

but that still gives the same error.

Also, in the .pro file I have:

```
QT       += core gui network
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Qt documentation `qFromBigEndian()` function argument type must be `const uchar *`:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtendian.html#qFromBigEndian

Try this:

```
qint32 peekedSize = qFromBigEndian<qint32>((const uchar*)&buffer);
```